# Did Chromecast update break debugging?

Tags: google-cast

Before the recent firmware update, web-based debugging (at port 9222) would persist between activities. Now any transition, say from the home screen to my app, stops the debugger with a message at the top saying...

```
Detached from the target
Remote debugging has been terminated with reason: target_closed.
Please re-attach to the new target.
```

It's not a huge problem to start a new debug window, but I'm worried that if the debugger isn't running when my app is loaded I won't get the benefit of the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" option.

Any details or workarounds would be appreciated.

UPDATE
Confirmed! In my case at least, the debugger stops with the above error and the latest version of my html, javascript, etc. does not get loaded

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a work around and see if it works: when your page is loaded, run `window.location.reload()` in the debug console to reload the page (so you get a full debugging info from the beginning without missing anything) or `window.location.reload(true)` to do the same and clear cache as well.

Comment: Yes that works to reload the receiver, but doing so breaks the link between the client sender (web or Android) and the receiver. I'm assuming the activityId becomes invalid because cast_api.sendMessage doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: What Chromecast load are you on?

Comment: Chromecast build is 14651. Receiver uses https://www.gstatic.com/cast/js/receiver/1.0/cast_receiver.js

Comment: Couple notes: I see the same debugger stop behavior using any of my whitelisted devices. I see the behavior on any activity switch, home screen to YouTube for example.

Comment: Is your android app designed to "join" a running session, if any, or it always launches a new one? If it is the former, then I imagine you can first reload the page and then "join" (or at least I am hoping you could).

Comment: I don't current have join working, but I get your point. I can resolve my cache problem from the server side by simply setting the html, js, css, etc. to a short (30s) expiration, but it's clear, at least in my case, that debugging is somewhat broken. Can you replicate? Is this a general problem?

Comment: There are technical changes that are being made for various reasons which make this more complicated than can be explained here. It seems broken, I agree but that is an artifact of some design considerations in other places that were unavoidable and once we release the official SDK, we can revisit this topic and talk about that more.

Comment: Thanks Ali. As I'm sure you're aware, begin able to debug the initial phase of a Chromecast app can be important, and I hope this will be addressed in the near future. I'm excited to see the "offical" SDK.